# the value of LiveData<List> just have one element

Tags: android-room, android-livedata

I query my database as below:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM employees")
public LiveData<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees();
```

and with one MediatorLiveData I observe on result like this:

```
data.addSource(DAO.getAllEmployees(), employeeList -> {
        if (employeeList==null) return;
        data.setValue(employeeList);
    });
```

Every time that data is inserted into employees table, this observer is called, but the problem is employeeList only has one item while db has more than one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault, I've done a mistake in parsers and the DB data was replaced because of `onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE`.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, it helped fixed the same issue for me.